# changing a layout in MainActivity from ArrayAdapter OnBindViewHolder

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

so i have my main activity which is as below and i have a custom adapter named StoryAdapter. the visibilty of the last linearlayout which is specified with storyImageContainer id (android:id="@+id/storyImageContainer") set to "GONE". i want to make it "VISIBLE" when i click on any items clicklistener of storyAdapter but im not able to find the linearlayout from onBindViewHolder or StoryAdapter.

1- the layout file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:textDirection="rtl"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">





        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/story"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/storiesbar"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


                </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>


            </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="5dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_shadow_2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


    </LinearLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_above="@id/view2"
            android:layout_below="@id/story"
            android:id="@+id/framelayoutmainpage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/story">


        </FrameLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="5dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_shadow_1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="8"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/mainpage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/homeImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_home_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/homeTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/b_nazanin"
                    android:text="صفحه اصلی"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/learnpage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/learnImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_library_books_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/learnTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/b_nazanin"
                    android:text="آموزش"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/servicepage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/serviceImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_dashboard_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/serviceTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/b_nazanin"
                    android:text="خدمات"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/aboutuspage"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/aboutImageView"
                    android:layout_width="30dp"
                    android:layout_height="30dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/ic_outline_insert_chart_24" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/aboutTextView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/b_nazanin"
                    android:text="درباره ما"
                    android:textColor="@color/gray_text"
                    android:textSize="15sp" />
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:background="@drawable/acclogo"
        android:id="@+id/storyImageContainer"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/storyImage"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        </ImageView>


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the kotlin code of MainActivity

```
 package com.myket.bahahesab

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import android.view.View
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.*
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var fragment : Fragment
    lateinit var framelayout : FrameLayout
    lateinit var fragmentManager: FragmentManager
    lateinit var fragmentTransaction : FragmentTransaction
    lateinit var storiesbar : RecyclerView




    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        var linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.storyImageContainer)
        storielist()





        //action bar and status bar
        window.statusBarColor = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.main_statusbarcolor)
        window.decorView.layoutDirection = View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL

        fragment = HomePageFragment();
        fragmentManager = supportFragmentManager
        fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.framelayoutmainpage, fragment).commit()

        var homeImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeImageView)
        var homeTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.homeTextView)
        homeImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24))
        homeTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))

        var mainpage = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.mainpage)
        var learnpage = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.learnpage)
        var servicepage = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.servicepage)
        var aboutuspage = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.aboutuspage)


        mainpage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {
                if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayoutmainpage) !is HomePageFragment){
                    fragment = HomePageFragment();
                    var fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.framelayoutmainpage, fragment).commit()

                    var homeImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeImageView)
                    var homeTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.homeTextView)
                    homeImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_home_24))
                    homeTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))

                    var learnImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.learnImageView)
                    var learnTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.learnTextView)
                    learnImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_library_books_24))
                    learnTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                    var serviceImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.serviceImageView)
                    var serviceTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.serviceTextView)
                    serviceImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_dashboard_24))
                    serviceTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                    var aboutImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.aboutImageView)
                    var aboutTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aboutTextView)
                    aboutImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_insert_chart_24))
                    aboutTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))


                }

        })

        learnpage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayoutmainpage) !is LearnPageFragment){
                fragment = LearnPageFragment()
                var fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.framelayoutmainpage, fragment).commit()

                var homeImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeImageView)
                var homeTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.homeTextView)
                homeImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_home_24))
                homeTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var learnImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.learnImageView)
                var learnTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.learnTextView)
                learnImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_library_books_24))
                learnTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))

                var serviceImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.serviceImageView)
                var serviceTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.serviceTextView)
                serviceImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_dashboard_24))
                serviceTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var aboutImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.aboutImageView)
                var aboutTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aboutTextView)
                aboutImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_insert_chart_24))
                aboutTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))
            }

        })

        servicepage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayoutmainpage) !is ServicePageFragment){
                fragment = ServicePageFragment()
                var fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.framelayoutmainpage, fragment).commit()

                var homeImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeImageView)
                var homeTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.homeTextView)
                homeImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_home_24))
                homeTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var learnImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.learnImageView)
                var learnTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.learnTextView)
                learnImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_library_books_24))
                learnTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var serviceImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.serviceImageView)
                var serviceTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.serviceTextView)
                serviceImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_dashboard_24))
                serviceTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))

                var aboutImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.aboutImageView)
                var aboutTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aboutTextView)
                aboutImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_insert_chart_24))
                aboutTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))
            }

        })

        aboutuspage.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {


            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.framelayoutmainpage) !is AboutPageFragment){
                fragment = AboutPageFragment()
                var fragmentTransaction2 = fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                fragmentTransaction2.replace(R.id.framelayoutmainpage, fragment).commit()

                var homeImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.homeImageView)
                var homeTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.homeTextView)
                homeImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_home_24))
                homeTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var learnImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.learnImageView)
                var learnTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.learnTextView)
                learnImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_library_books_24))
                learnTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var serviceImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.serviceImageView)
                var serviceTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.serviceTextView)
                serviceImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_outline_dashboard_24))
                serviceTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.gray_text))

                var aboutImageView = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.aboutImageView)
                var aboutTextView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.aboutTextView)
                aboutImageView.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_baseline_insert_chart_24))
                aboutTextView.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black))
            }

        })



    }

    fun storielist(){
        storiesbar = findViewById(R.id.storiesbar)
        var storiesList = ArrayList<Story>()
        storiesList.add(Story(false))
        storiesList.add(Story(false))
        storiesList.add(Story(false))
        storiesList.add(Story(false))
        storiesList.add(Story(false))





        var storiesAdapter = StoryAdapter(storiesList, this)
        storiesbar.adapter = storiesAdapter
        storiesbar.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false)



    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        finishAffinity()
        finish()
    }
}
```

adapter code ******************

```
package com.myket.bahahesab

import android.app.ActivityOptions
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.graphics.Color
import android.hardware.camera2.params.ColorSpaceTransform
import android.os.Build
import android.util.Log
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.view.animation.Animation
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import kotlinx.coroutines.NonDisposableHandle.parent
import java.util.zip.Inflater

class StoryAdapter(var dataSet : List<Story>, var context : Context) : RecyclerView.Adapter<StoryAdapter.ViewHolder>() {

    class ViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){
        var cardview : CardView = view.findViewById<CardView>(R.id.outlinestory)
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        var layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        var view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.story_item, parent, false)
        var viewholder = StoryAdapter.ViewHolder(view)
        return viewholder
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {

        if (dataSet[position].seen){
            holder.cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.seenStory))
        }else {
            holder.cardview.setCardBackgroundColor(context.resources.getColor(R.color.main_bahahesabColor))
        }

        holder.cardview.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener {

        })

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return dataSet.count()
    }

}
```

```
i used findViewById and tried finding it through context but was enabled cause it said the variable lateinit is nit initialized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way is to pass a callback listener to the adapter

```
// in your adapter
var storyClickedListener: ((story: Story) -> Unit)? = null

// in your item click listener
holder.cardview.setOnClickListener {
    // if there's a listener, call it and pass the clicked Story
    storyClickedListener?.invoke(dataSet[position])
}
```

Then in your Activity or whatever, pass a listener function to the Adapter which does whatever you need to do:

```
storiesAdapter.storyClickedListener = { story ->
    // react to the click
}
```

That way the adapter doesn't need to know anything about the Activity it's inside (and it shouldn't really) - it just has a listener it can inform when an event happens. The owner of the listener handles the details of what happens in response.

The classic Java way to do this would be with an interface - create an interface with a callback function, make the Activity implement it, pass the Activity to the Adapter as an instance of `YourCallbackInterface` so it can call that listener function. Same thing, but wih Kotlin you can just pass a function like this, nice and simple!

Also you don't *need* to pass a `Story` as a parameter, but usually you'd want to pass some info about what's been clicked